# World edit wood rotation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

What command should I use to rotate wood to S,N,W,E,D and U?

I read the entire world edit guide and tried some things but all the results are not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you look up the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log#Data_values) for the data values?

You can rotate wood to face in whatever direction you want with WorldEdit by simply substituting `[Data Value]` with the appropriate one that you're looking for.

After selecting the region with your `//wand` (AKA. a wooden axe by default),

```
//set Log:[Data Value] OR //set 17:[Data Value]
------------------------------------------------------
| DIRECTION        |  Oak  | Spruce | Birch | Jungle |
------------------------------------------------------
| Up/down          | 0     | 1      | 2     | 3      |
| East/West        | 4     | 5      | 6     | 7      |
| North/South      | 8     | 9      | 10    | 11     |
| Bark-only        | 12    | 13     | 14    | 15     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

If you're looking for Acaica and Dark Oak, use the following values:

```
//set Log2:[Data Value] OR //set 162:[Data Value]
------------------------------------------
| DIRECTION        |  Acaica  | Dark Oak |
------------------------------------------
| Up/down          | 0        | 1        |
| East/West        | 4        | 5        |
| North/South      | 8        | 9        |
| Bark-only        | 12       | 13       |
------------------------------------------
```