# How to rotate blocks while giving a set command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I have two wooden blocks, one facing up and one facing the side as you can see in the image, I do not want the block to be vertical, I want it to be horizontal when I give the command `//set <block>`

Does the `//set <block>` command have more than one argument to do this? Or is there another command to rotate an already placed block?

The command I am using is this:
//set 17:1

[image]
The server version is 1.5.2, so the WorldEdit plugin version is
5.5.6

Comment: What have you tried, what have you researched? I don't know much about worldedit, but I would try changing the `1` to something else and seeing what that does. Also, in which version are you? Block IDs have been switched away from numbers a looong time ago.

Comment: The server version is 1.5.2, so the WorldEdit plugin version is
5.5.6, I updated the post.

Comment: And what have you tried to solve your problem? The [help] says that we expect at least a bit of own effort from askers.

Comment: I was thinking of giving a // copy and // rotate and then // paste, but it is very laborious because I will need to walk to paste according to my position. I wanted to do this via ***//set block rotation*** command

Comment: Alright then, it's a proper question now. I still don't know much about worldedit, but have you tried changing the `1` to something else?

Comment: The number 1 serves to catch id of similar blocks, if I change it to something else it will pick up a different block.

Comment: You're right, in place of 1 you have to enter another number to rotate the block. I noticed on this other stackoverflow site: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209959/world-edit-wood-rotation